# Converting awk output to integer

Tags: bash, awk

I have elaborated an `awk` command which gathers the output of a shell:

```
val=$(./cli.sh --file=scripts/monitor.sh | awk '/result/{print $3}')
echo $val
```

Returns:

```
"75"
```

As you can see the output is correctly returned, however I'd need to cast it to integer. Is there an `awk` function to do it?

Comment: https://www.gnu.org/software/gawk/manual/html_node/String-Functions.html

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use [`gsub()`](https://www.gnu.org/software/gawk/manual/html_node/String-Functions.html) to remove the quotes:

```
$ echo '"3"' | awk '{gsub("\"", "", $1); print}'
3
```

In your case, this should make:

```
val=$(./cli.sh ... | awk '/result/{gsub("\"", "", $3); print $3}')
```

#### Test

Sample file:

```
$ cat a
returns a b "75"
returns b c "33"
returns d e 7
hello z z 7
```

And let's run it:

```
$ awk '/return/ {gsub("\"", "", $4); print $4}' a
75
33
7
```

Answer (score 0):

Try:

```
val=$(./cli.sh --file=scripts/monitor.sh | awk '/result/{print substr($3, 2, length($2)-1)}')
echo $val
```

Comment: Thanks. However it returns 7 instead of 75.

Comment: This is the case with example from OP? or OP can just remove "" from the output very simple.